# Audit logs POST/PUT/DELETE operations for Microservices in Azure

Tags: logging, microservices, azure-aks, azure-monitoring

I have an application with about 50 Microservices in Azure using AKS. I want to log all activities that users do on all POST/PUT/DELETE methods. Do I need to add code to all my operations to have these kind of audit history? Or there is an Azure service that we can use?

I am not intresserted in security or technical logs, but in who did what.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider Application Insights product available in Azure. It supports various types of apps and for some you do not need to do much if at all to get the data on latencies, failures and much more.

Are you running any mesh product on your cluster by chance? Say, Istio?

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to check the application. I want to know who f.ex. deleted an item by clicking on a button. An pure Audit Trail.

Comment: Well, this is much easier said then done, unfortunately. The fact that DELETE request was processed needs to by intercepted. That can be done without much trouble with multiple app monitoring solutions such as AppInsights, NewRelic, AppDynamics, etc. There are some other lighter weight alternatives too... But you need to intercept the request is some way. You can also use various Mesh solutions such as Istio and plugins to build Audit log.

Comment: The other part (tracking "who's done it") is tricky. Services usually use "trusted party" auth, etc and rarely pass actual user name in the payload - therefore you'd normally see service ABC called service XYZ and requested DELETE on certain object. You won't know the original user. Distributed tracing may be able to get you that information and again, you'd need app monitoring product to do it for you. Application Insights can do it. You do not necessarily need to instrument your services and redeploy in case you're running K8s cluster with Mesh technology, thus, I asked if you do...